# Работа с анонимными функциями

Tags: php, массивы, анонимная-функция

Есть массив товаров

```
array (
  0 => 'Наименование товара №1_~-250$_~-99$',
  1 => 'Наименование товара №2_~-699$_~-399$',
  2 => 'Наименование товара №3_~-299$_~-149$',
)
```

Еще массив параметров, которым соответствую характеристики товаров

```
 array (
  0 => 'Наименование',
  1 => 'Старая цена',
  2 => 'Новая цена',
)
```

Получаю эти данные из `<input type="checkbox" name="upsell[]">`, атрибут `value` заполняю с помощью `JS` считывая содержимое определенных тегов и через конкатенацию соединяю три строки в одну. Крякозябра `_~-` - это разделитель, которым в `JS` соединяю строки, потом в `PHP` разбираю строку с помощью `explode()`

```
$upsells = ['Наименование товара №1_~-250$_~-99$', 'Наименование товара №2_~-699$_~-399$', 'Наименование товара №3_~-299$_~-149$',];
$orderDetails = ['Наименование', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'];    

$enumerationGoods = function($upsells) {
            
        $productInformation = explode('_~-', $upsells); 
        $numberProduct .= '<b>Товар №</b> '.($number += 1).':<br />';
        $orderDetails = ['Наименование', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'];
            
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($productInformation); $i++) {
            $nomination .= '<b>'.$orderDetails[$i].':</b> '.$productInformation[$i].'<br />';
        }   
        return $numberProduct . $nomination;
    };
        
    $html_parts = array_map($enumerationGoods, $upsells); 
    echo implode('', $html_parts);
```

Результат

```
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №1
Старая цена: 250$
Новая цена: 99$
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №2
Старая цена: 699$
Новая цена: 399$
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №3
Старая цена: 299$
Новая цена: 149$
```

Как исправить работу счетчика товаров?

Comment: `return` внутри `foreach` - после первой итерации вы выходите из функции.

Comment: смотрите `array_map` и `implode`

Comment: Не увидел, что еще в цикле `return` делаю спасибо. Подправил немного решение, теперь выводиться `Товар №1, Товар №2, Товар №3` и в секции с `Товар №3` выводиться три товара, а не каждый товар со своим номером по счету. Не подскажите что еще упускаю?

Comment: `implode('', $nomination)` не должен добавляться в конце, а должен добавляться для каждого элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты не можешь понять, как работают анонимные функции - ну не используй их:

```
$upsells = ['Наименование товара №1_~-250$_~-99$', 'Наименование товара №2_~-699$_~-399$', 'Наименование товара №3_~-299$_~-149$',];
$orderDetails = ['Наименование', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'];

$text = '';
foreach ($upsells as $upsell) {
    $productInformation = explode('_~-', $upsell);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($productInformation); $i++) {
        $text .= '<b>'.$orderDetails[$i].':</b> '.$productInformation[$i].'<br />';
    }    
}

echo $text;
```

[Пример](https://3v4l.org/sSRml).

Comment: Спасибо в очередной раз, с вопросом третьим или четвертым помогаете. Да, не осилил анонимную функцию. Зато  `.=` - смекалки не хватило использовать, чтоб так легко решить задачу. Надуюсь и я  так научусь задачи щелкать на раз два

Comment: Как можно нумерацию товаров добавить `Товар №1... Товар №2 и т.д` ?

Comment: Также как и все остальное: `$text .= '<b>Товар №</b> '.($numberProduct += 1).':<br />';`

Comment: Подскажите, как вывести и данные о товаре и нумерацию в одной переменной?

Comment: Задай новый вопрос, я не знаю какие это переменные, откуда они взялись и что с ними не так.

Comment: Так я же описал, где берутся данные, и что хочу с ними сделать

Comment: `$mail->Body = 'Новый заказ ' . $text;` или что?

Comment: Это я описывал, что использую ‘phpMailer’ и почему решил использовать анонимную функцию

Answer (score 1):

К `$upsells` можно применить `array_map` и получить массив кусков html.

Анонимная функция передается **в** `array_map`, получает на вход 1 `$upsell` и возвращает 1 кусок html, который ему соответствует.

Потом куски html можно соединить через `implode`

```
$render_upsell = function($upsell) {
    $productInformation = explode('_~-', $upsell);
    ...
    return '<b>'.$orderDetails[$i].':</b> '.$productInformation[$i].'<br />';
};

$html_parts = array_map($render_upsell, $upsells);
```

Comment: Не хватает мне ума катастрофически, не понимаю что должна анонимная функция делать, постоянно `Null` получаю из неё, при попытке получить 1 '$upsell'. Использую `foreach` для перебора `$upsells`, после `explode` разбираю строку по разделителю, после в `for` получаю элемент. Все тоже самое делаю(

Comment: добавиол пример; потом `$html = implode('',$html_parts)`